# How to send Hex Data to Raspberry Pi Serial Port using Python

Tags: python

How to send some Hex Data to a usb device..

Comment: What do you mean with "Hex Data"? Do you want to send binary (raw) data on the wire, or an ascii string which the Pi then will convert to binary? What have you tried, or where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/). That is available on RasPi and PC. For sending/receiving data, use `bytes` (constant) or `bytearray` (variable), which are standard Python types (note the differences between Python3 and 2).

Comment: It just about connecting Serial port to Raspberry Pi We want some example about sending/receiving data in hex form in raspi.